# Calculating price per use

Tags: javascript, algorithm, google-apps-script

How would you work out the price per use of an item - in my case an exercise bike -

A) Total cost / number of uses

or

B) Total cost halved per use

and how would this be done in code (Javascript specifically google sheet scripting) 
Right now none of my code is even beginning to come close to the two potential answers Right now its 6 uses (value automatically changes in H1 of my spreadsheet) and cost of $40 
Currently i think it should be done the way B says and this is my attempt but its not giving me the expected output and i have tried a few other methods however the division within the for loop doesn't seem to get repeated even when i have only had one line.

I have removed many of the var definitions just to make the post cleaner

newppr = new price per ride

ppr = price per ride

oldppr - old price per ride

pob = price of bike

```
var numofRides = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('H1').getValue(); //gets number of rides from cell H1
for (i = 0; i <= numofRides; i++) {
  oldppr = pob / 2; 
  newppr = oldppr / 2;
  newppr = newppr / 2;
  ppr = newppr;
}
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F3').setValue(newppr);   //sets new value to cell F3 
}
```

Am i making this over complicated and which should it be - if its A then its an easy fix but i have some doubt about which one it is any help will be gratefully received

Comment: Welcome. "How would you work out the price per use of an item?" - that's more of an accounting issue that would be off topic here; and I also smell an aroma of an assigned homework task, otherwise why write a script. Always better to be up front, it won't stop people helping.

Comment: First. Troubleshooting. Insert this as the last line in the loop, immediately after `ppr=newppr` and before `}`...`Logger.log("i="+i+", oldppr:"+oldppr+". newppr:"+newppr+", ppr:"+ppr);` This will tell you the values of the variables for each iteration of the loop, and you'll notice that `oldppr:20. newppr:5, ppr:5` is the same result for each iteration; so something going wrong here.

Comment: What is the purpose of the loop? To calculate a value as a condition changes, but did you notice that your code generated 7 (not 6) uses? That's because the initial expression was zero and the condition was  "<= numofRides". By making the condition "<=", it counted from zero to 6 = seven. Normally if you start at zero, the condition operator is "<".

Comment: Your question isn't clear whether you are discussing pricing policy or depreciation. In the case pricing: "Total cost halved per use" - the total cost is $40, so half is $20 for each and every use - no need for a loop there; and that could easily be the case for some high demand, specialised products. OTOH, "Total cost/number of uses" also generates a flat rate/use but it requires an estimate of the total number of uses. Say your bike could survive 1000 uses, then $40/1000 = $0.04cents per use, and that would be a pricing policy that might apply to commodity-type products.

Comment: Thanks to Tedinoz for the final response, this is the exact information i wanted and thank you for your time - just for a bit of clarification, Its a bike I already have and want to justify the price of it with some nice stats on my personal tracking spreadsheet. 
your final comment is the best its just instead of the $40 / 1000 it will be my current number of uses! many thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Total cost/number of uses" also generates a flat rate/use but it requires an estimate of the total number of uses. Say your bike could survive 1000 uses, then $40/1000 = $0.04cents per use, and that would be a pricing policy that might apply to commodity-type products"

Thanks to Tedinoz for the response, this is the exact information I couldn't find and thank you for your time

Just for a bit of clarification, Its a bike I already have and want to justify the price of due to financial reasons alongside some nice stats on my personal tracking spreadsheet. Your final comment is the best it's just instead of the $40 / 1000 it will be my current number of uses so there is no need for code to attempt to half the cost for each use! Turns out I was really overthinking this and it is just a simple cell / cell. Many many thanks.